# referencing powershell files in main file

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a powershell file with some utility functions.

Is it possible to reference this utility file in another powershell file and use the utility classes from it? If so, how can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can “dot-source” a script to run it in the current scope. If your utility script is something like `utils.ps1`, then you can do

```
. .\utils.ps1
```

and all functions that are declared in the script are available to you. This doesn't stop with functions, though, script-scoped variables as well and all code in the script will actually run, so be careful whether that's really what you want.

A nicer option, but maybe a bit overkill for a few utility functions, would be a module containing said functions. With modules you have finer-grained control over what gets imported and what parts are private to the module.

Comment: One other great benefit of using modules is that all imports are removed once the module has been unloaded.

Comment: Script modules also have caveats and different behaviour of some features. I would not recommend migration to modules for existing working code. Yes, modules are handy. But play with a new code.